# An additive combinatoric probability question

Tags: pr.probability, additive-combinatorics

I asked the question in cs-theory stack exchange but was advised a pure math forum would be more apt. Link to the question:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52930/an-additive-combinatoric-probability-question
For the sake of completeness I am once again writing the problem:

Let $A,B \subset [d]$, where $[d] = \{0,...,d \}$, such that $A\cap B = \phi$ and $|A| = |B| = \frac{d+1}{2}$. I was studying the size of $|(2A \cup 2B) \triangle (A+B)|$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference, for a research problem. Note that $2A = \{a+b | a,b \in A \}$ and $A+B = \{a+b | a \in A, b\in B  \} $. I ran some simulations for random subsets of $A, B$ for different sizes of $d$ and I conjecture that for randomized subsets $A,B\subset [d]$ satisfying the above property, $\mathbb{E}\left[|(2A\cup 2B)\triangle (A+B)|\right] = \mathcal{O}(1)$. I have been trying to prove the conjecture for some time but have been unable to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both $A+A$ and $A+B$ coincide with $\{0,1,\ldots,2d\}$ upto finitely many elements asymptotically almost surely. That's because an element $x$ which has $f(x)$ representations $x=u+v$ for $u,v\in [d]$ does not belong to $A+A$ or $A+B$ with probability at most $\exp(-f(x)/10)$ or like that (these sets should miss all these pairs).

Comment: Try using linearity of expectation to evaluate the expectation as the sum over $x \in [2d]$ of the probability that $x$ is in the symmetric difference.